# Make template function select type by function parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I got some classes like

```
class A {
 public:
  void OnStageOne() {}
  void OnStageTwo() {}
  void OnStageThree() {}
};

class B {
 public:
  void OnStageOne() {}
  void OnStageTwo() {}
  void OnStageThree() {}
};

class C {
 public:
  void OnStageOne() {}
  void OnStageTwo() {}
  void OnStageThree() {}
};
```

and I got some vectors to store them:

```
std::vector<A> va;
std::vector<B> vb;
std::vector<C> vc;
```

now I need some operations like this: call `OnStageXXX` on all elements of a vector, so I wrote a template function like this:

```
template <typename T, void(T::*F)()>
void ForAll(std::vector<T> vector) {
  for (auto& item : vector) {
    (item.*F)();
  }
}
```

It works fine, except that I have to use syntax like this:

```
ForAll<A, &A::OnStageOne>(va);
```

Since the first template parameter can be deduced for the parameter `va`, is there any way I can make the code more cleaner? Like `ForAll<OnStageOne>(va);`?

Or, if this is an A/B question, this there any way I can wrote things like `ForAll<OnStageXXX>(va);` to call `OnStageXXX` on each element of a vector?

P.S. I tried with `std::for_each`, but this makes the syntax even longer. I'm here to seek for a shorter syntax to do this, if any.

Comment: `ForAll<&A::OnStageOne>(va);` is possible

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki, seems not:`error: no matching function for call to 'ForAll'`, I used C++17

Comment: I mean with some changes of course. And it's more a question to you, would that suffice.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Appreciate if you can give me a clue.

Comment: @ravenisadesk Could the member function pointer be function parameter instead of template parameter?

Comment: @songyuanyao, Of cause, as long as the syntax is cleaner, any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17):

```
template <auto F, typename T>
void ForAll(std::vector<T>& vector) {
  for (auto& item : vector) {
    (item.*F)();
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
ForAll<&A::OnStageOne>(va);
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/748801fa9299aed6)

---

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20):

```
constexpr auto OnStageOne = [] (auto& t) -> decltype(t.OnStageOne()) {
  return t.OnStageOne();
};
constexpr auto OnStageTwo = [] (auto& t) -> decltype(t.OnStageTwo()) {
  return t.OnStageTwo();
};
constexpr auto OnStageThree = [] (auto& t) -> decltype(t.OnStageThree()) {
  return t.OnStageThree();
};

template <auto F, typename T>
    requires requires (T t) { F(t); }
void ForAll(std::vector<T>& vector) {
  for (auto& item : vector) {
    F(item);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
ForAll<OnStageOne>(va);
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed5c67b17ac2cf06)

---

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) / [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) (and before without the ranged based for loop):

```
struct OnStageOne {
  template <typename T>
  void operator()(T& t) const { t.OnStageOne(); }
};

struct OnStageTwo {
  template <typename T>
  void operator()(T& t) const { t.OnStageTwo(); }
};

struct OnStageThree {
  template <typename T>
  void operator()(T& t) const { t.OnStageThree(); }
};

template <typename F, typename T>
void ForAll(std::vector<T>& vector) {
  for (auto& item : vector) {
    F{}(item);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
ForAll<OnStageOne>(va);
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2219ba936b768fe)

Comment: Hi, can I make it more shorter, for remove `&A::`? I got a feeling C++ does not work in this way, but I still want to ask...

Comment: Is this the featue "concept" in C++20?

Comment: Thanks, I would choose  option 3 even though there are more structures to write

Comment: @ravenisadesk You could generate them with a single macro.

Answer (score 0):

This answer approaches the question from an "XY problem" perspective:

> Or, if this is an A/B question, this there any way I can wrote things like ForAll(va); to call OnStageXXX on each element of a vector?

It seems that your intent is to implement static polymorphism for the classes `A`, `B` and `C` over a (not directly enforced) static interface, in this case, a number of `OnStageXXX` member functions. Instead of solving the problem of *"how to (static-)polymorphically invoke via pointers to member functions"* you may want to look over how you implement the "static interface" of you classes.

As a first step, instead of using separate non-template member functions for the `OnStageXXX` functions, you could implement them as a member function template parameterized over some tag, say an `enum class` `StageTag`. This would allow you to invoke the `forAll(...)` function using the tag instead of a pointer to member function to choose which member function specialization to invoke. E.g.:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

enum class StageTag { kOne, kTwo, kThree };

class A {
public:
  template <StageTag> void OnStage() const = delete;
};

template <> void A::OnStage<StageTag::kOne>() const {
  std::cout << "A OnStage kOne\n";
}

template <> void A::OnStage<StageTag::kTwo>() const {
  std::cout << "A OnStage kTwo\n";
}

template <> void A::OnStage<StageTag::kThree>() const {
  std::cout << "A OnStage kThree\n";
}

class B {
public:
  template <StageTag> void OnStage() const = delete;
};

template <> void B::OnStage<StageTag::kOne>() const {
  std::cout << "B OnStage kOne\n";
}

template <> void B::OnStage<StageTag::kTwo>() const {
  std::cout << "B OnStage kTwo\n";
}

template <> void B::OnStage<StageTag::kThree>() const {
  std::cout << "B OnStage kThree\n";
}

template <StageTag kTag, typename T> void ForAll(const std::vector<T> &vector) {
  for (auto &item : vector) {
    item.template OnStage<kTag>();
  }
}

int main() {
  const std::vector<A> va(3);
  const std::vector<B> vb(2);

  ForAll<StageTag::kThree>(va);
  // A OnStage kThree
  // A OnStage kThree
  // A OnStage kThree

  ForAll<StageTag::kOne>(vb);
  // B OnStage kOne
  // B OnStage kOne

  return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, instead of using specializations over `StageTag`, you could use tag dispatch to dispatch to the appropriate non-template member function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

enum class StageTag { kOne, kTwo, kThree };

class A {
private:
  template <StageTag> struct ATag {};

public:
  template <StageTag kTag> void OnStage() const { OnStage(ATag<kTag>{}); }

private:
  void OnStage(ATag<StageTag::kOne>) const { std::cout << "A OnStage kOne\n"; }

  void OnStage(ATag<StageTag::kTwo>) const { std::cout << "A OnStage kTwo\n"; }

  void OnStage(ATag<StageTag::kThree>) const {
    std::cout << "A OnStage kThree\n";
  }
};

class B {
private:
  template <StageTag> struct BTag {};

public:
  template <StageTag kTag> void OnStage() const { OnStage(BTag<kTag>{}); }

private:
  void OnStage(BTag<StageTag::kOne>) const { std::cout << "B OnStage kOne\n"; }

  void OnStage(BTag<StageTag::kTwo>) const { std::cout << "B OnStage kTwo\n"; }

  void OnStage(BTag<StageTag::kThree>) const {
    std::cout << "B OnStage kThree\n";
  }
};

template <StageTag kTag, typename T> void ForAll(const std::vector<T> &vector) {
  for (auto &item : vector) {
    item.template OnStage<kTag>();
  }
}

int main() {
  const std::vector<A> va(3);
  const std::vector<B> vb(2);

  ForAll<StageTag::kThree>(va);
  // A OnStage kThree
  // A OnStage kThree
  // A OnStage kThree

  ForAll<StageTag::kOne>(vb);
  // B OnStage kOne
  // B OnStage kOne

  return 0;
}
```

You may also want to look into the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to enforce your static interface.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, at first, I did not considered any thing about static polymorphism, just get tired of writing bunch of code to do the for each thing, you suggestion is great, but I want make my class clean, and probably do the magic in some helper classes.

Comment: @ravenisadesk as the member functions of your different classes are obviously following a common interface, you may want to both/either enforce (common abstract interface (virtual functions) or static polymorphism via e.g. CRTP) and leverage this. Do you want to be able to also mock these member function calls in tests? Then a common abstract interface would help. As it is now, your common interface is not directly enforced (but indirectly by how e.g. a generic function is invoked with objects from the different classes). Hidden interfaces can end up quite confusing to maintain, though.

Comment: Yes, in the real case, I got a base class with virtual functions called "StageOne", "StageTwo"... I just hide this fact in this question, sorry for that...It does look like a CRTP in this question...